# Swift - (Strava API) Bad Request, Redirect URI Invalid

Tags: swift, strava, aswebauthenticationsession, strava-api-v3

I am prompting the user to connect to Strava, and when I open the URL, I am given a page with JSON telling me that it was a bad request, and that my redirect uri was invalid.

```
{ "message":"Bad Request",
    "errors":[{
        "resource":"Application",
        "field":"redirect_uri",
        "code":"invalid"
    }]
}
```

When I do the following,

```
https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={{clientId}}&redirect_uri=google.com&response_type=code&scope=read_all,activity:read_all,profile:read_all
```

I get this error. So I know something is up when trying this on the iOS Simulator. When I do it in Postman, it seems to work just fine.

Here's the request I am putting into my Xcode project in Swift

```
let url: String = "https://www.strava.com/oauth/mobile/authorize?client_id=97936&redirect_uri=google.com%3A%2F%2F\(Keys.fallbackUrl)&response_type=code&approval_prompt=auto&scope=read"
guard let authenticationUrl = URL(string: url) else { return }
        
authSession = ASWebAuthenticationSession(url: authenticationUrl, callbackURLScheme: "google.com") { url, error in
    if let error = error {
        print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        if let url = url {
            print(url)
        }
    }
}
        
authSession?.presentationContextProvider = self
authSession?.start()
```

I also managed to make a working universal link so when one types this link into Safari when already having the downloaded app, it takes directly to the app. So eventually, I will replace it with my URL: kette.netlify.app

**Some things I have tried:**

- Using https:// in front of the callback uri and redirect uri. The iOS Simulator crashes.
- Using other URLS aside from my kette.netlify.app one.
- trying Deep Linking AND Universal Links.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks so much

Comment: You're trying to redirect into what kind of URL exactly? `google.com://??` Is it all percent escaped?

Comment: @Larme, I used google.com as an example, but I am trying to use universial links in Swift to get back into my app. And yes, google.com:// doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a procedure to have a redirect uri i.e. Strava only supports the authorized redirect. So, we have to set a **domain** for the **callback** and then we can just continue without having **Invalid redirect_uri error**.

You can set the domain from:

> Strava > Settings > My API Application > Edit > Authorization Callback Domain > Save

There you have to set `google.com` **it will not accept the scope** like `https`, `http`, etc.

**NOTE:** Keep in mind to change the domain when you are done testing and in live production.

For your response you can check [strava docs](https://developers.strava.com/docs/authentication/) where it is mentioned.

> URL to which the user will be redirected after authentication. Must be within the callback domain specified by the application. localhost and 127.0.0.1 are white-listed.